# WPF Page->Canvas->TabControl->TabItem->Grid->DataGrid not showing vertical scrollbars

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, scrollbar

OK, I too, have come across the "vertical scrollbar not showing" problem, the suggested solutions either don't work or aren't applicable in this case.

The desire is to show not one, but two data grids, side by side, each with it's own data source on an application that will respond correctly to user resizing, meaning that the grids will expand and contract as expected. The grids should be "anchored" and render accordingly (oh, how I miss the days of WinForms and actual, simple anchoring!).

The first grid will normally show insufficient rows to trigger a vertical scrollbar, that's OK.

The second datagrids' content is based on the selected row of the first datagrid, meaning when a user selects a row in the first datagrid (column 0), an SQL statement is executed and the result shows in the other datagrid (the one in column 1).

What does happen is that the second grids' content, if larger than the displayed size, will continue to render (out of sight) pushing the pages container items (a status bar at the bottom, not shown in the code) to one side and continue to render right off the applications boundaries (not visible, but the grid behaves as if it has infinite room to display).

What I don't get is a nice, paged grid with a vertical scroll bar.

I'm using MVVMLight as the toolkit and the corresponding ViewModel works as designed. The data isn't the issue, just the rendering.

I'm pretty sure the solution is quite simple, I just don't have the xaml experience yet (I'm a newbie with this) to figure it out. I've tried enclosing the grids in various other containers (DockPanel, StackPanel with orientation=Horizontal, etc.) but just can't seem to get it right. I even tried binding the row height to the tab control actual height - fail.

So...a little help with a tutorial explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the complete xaml (save that I have removed extraneous tab pages) for the page:

```
    <Page x:Class="GetSchemaExplorerMsSqlSvr.DbMetaDataPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GetSchemaExplorerMsSqlSvr"
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
      xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
      Height="Auto"
            Width="Auto"
      Title="DbMetaDataPage"
            x:Name="pgDbMetaDataPage"
      Background="{StaticResource YellowBackground}"
      DataContext="{Binding MainWindowVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
      >
  <Canvas>
    <TabControl x:Name="tcDbMetaData" Height="Auto"  Width="Auto">
            <TabItem x:Name="tiDbMetaData" Header="Get Schema" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid Margin="1,1,1,1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DataGrid
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        x:Name="dgDbMetaData"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetSchemaMetaData, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMetaDataItem, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    />
                    <DataGrid
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MetaDataCollectionInfo, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </Canvas>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are setting your TabControl as a Child of a Canvas. It is used to set abolute positioning of its Child elements. Since you don't need to set abolute positions, you should just remove your Canvas and set the content of your Page to be your TabControl directly.

From MSDN:

> Child elements of a Canvas are always given the full size that they desire. As a result, vertical alignment and horizontal alignment have no effect inside a Canvas.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your code would then be:

```
<Page...>
    <TabControl ...>
        <TabItem ...>
           <Grid ...>
               <DataGrid Grid.Column="0".../>
               <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" .../>
           </Grid>
        </TabItem>
     </TabControl>
</Page>
```

Comment: Ha! Go figure! I just discovered that on my own and was going to triumphantly trumpet my success only to find this answer. Thank you for both the quick response and the correct answer. You get marked as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed about above, removing the Canvas element solved the problem. The altered xaml is posted below just for the sake of reference. The result isn't pretty, but right now I'm looking for functional and this does the trick.

```
<Page x:Class="GetSchemaExplorerMsSqlSvr.DbMetaDataPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GetSchemaExplorerMsSqlSvr"
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
      xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
      Height="Auto"
            Width="Auto"
      Title="DbMetaDataPage"
            x:Name="pgDbMetaDataPage"
      Background="{StaticResource YellowBackground}"
      DataContext="{Binding MainWindowVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
      >
    <TabControl x:Name="tcDbMetaData" Height="Auto"  Width="Auto">
        <TabItem x:Name="tiDbMetaData" Header="Get Schema" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="{StaticResource YellowBackground}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DataGrid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        x:Name="dgDbMetaData"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetSchemaMetaData, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMetaDataItem, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    />
                    <DataGrid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MetaDataCollectionInfo, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    />
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="30" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" Content="Fetch MetaData"/>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tables">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Views">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Stored Procedures">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Functions">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Page>
```